# Настройка доступа в интернет для контейнера OpenVZ

Tags: linux, виртуальная-машина, openvz, bridge

Как настроить режим моста для контейнера в OpenVZ?
Я заходил на официальный сайт с документацией и не смог найти такой информации.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, создайте новый контейнер, используя команду "vzctl create". Затем запустите контейнер, при помощи "vzctl start". Во-вторых, настройте сетевой интерфейс контейнера для работы в режиме моста, для этого введите команду "vzctl set" и укажите параметр "NETIF_ADD2" со значением "ifname=eth0,bridge=br0". Настройка закончена.
Перезапустите контейнер  ("vzctl restart").
P.S. В этом примере eth0 - это сетевой интерфейс контейнера, который будет использоваться в режиме моста, а br0 это имя моста, к которому будет подключен этот интерфейс. Проверь, что мост br0 есть и нормально настроен.

Comment: Если я создаю контейнер при помощи prlctl, то этот способ тоже будет работать? https://docs.openvz.org/openvz_users_guide.webhelp/_creating_containers.html